# How to read cookies not set by Flask

Tags: python, wordpress, cookies, flask, session-cookies

I have a Flask site that runs inside an iframe of a wordpress site.

Both sites are on the same domain. That is, the wordpress site is on something like www.example.com and Flask site is on api.example.com.

I need to show some user specific stuff in the iframe. So how do I read a cookie that was set by wordpress in Flask? Or check if it is set? 
Basically, I want to know if the user is logged in or not (session cookie present) and their username.

The best would be if I could somehow integrate the Flask-Login plugin with the actual Wordpress login, however, I do not expect that to be possible.

Comment: You can't check logged-in status via a cookie. Logged in status is stored server-side in a session variable. The WP Cookie is only a session ID that ties a user to a session instance.

Comment: But you can create a rest service that given the Id returns if it is valid and the username

Answer (score 0):

When a cookie is created its domain is set. You need to ensure that the domain is set so that both sites [domain match](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.3) the cookie domain. For example `example.com` will allow the cookies to be viewed by both sites or put another way they will be set along with the request to both servers.

The wordpress login can be integrated with Flask. You will need to extract the session id/cookie contents and then make a request to the wordpress site.

Flask Code:

```
request.cookies.get('username')  # get single cookie
request.cookies  # get all as dict
```

[Cookie attribute](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.cookies)

This requests check if the session is valid and returns the user credentials.
If it succeeds - meaning the user can be automatically logged in - you then invoke [cookies](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask.ext.login.login_user)

Note: You will have to synchronize the sessions manually. When a session is created on the api side it will continue to exist until it expires or you manually call logout. Also if you log out of the wordpress side the flask session will continue to exist

More info on [cookies](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask.ext.login.login_user)

Comment: This: "The wordpress login can be integrated with Flask. You will need to extract the session id/cookie contents and then make a request to the wordpress site." This is what I want to know how to do. How do I extract the session id and cookie contents?