# Read cookies not set by Flask

Tags: javascript, python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cookies

I'm trying to integrate Facebook into my Flask app. The [Facebook SDK for JavaScript](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript) is seamless and really easy to use. But I'm having trouble passing data server-side (all I really need is a user's facebook ID). Here's my barebones flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    print('cookies', request.cookies)
    return render_template('get_fb_cookies.html')

@app.route('/set_key')
def set_key():
    session['key'] = 'value'
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here's my barebones template which allows the user to login/logout (and utilize various other parts of the facebook api) client-side:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '<app-id>',
        cookies    : true,
        version    : 'v2.10' // use graph api version 2.10
      });
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
      });
    };

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";  // minified version version
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        FB.api('/me', function(response){
          console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
          console.log('ID: ' + response.id)
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Not connected.')
      }
    };
  </script>

  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <h1>Get Facebook Cookies</h1>
  <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Reading this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530213/how-to-read-cookies-not-set-by-flask), it appears I need to access the cookies server-side but `request.cookies` is simply giving me the cookie set by `flask.session`. Maybe I need to change the **Domain** for the cookies facebook sets. Right now there's about ten of them set to `.facebook.com`. I figure I need to set them to `localhost` (or wherever my server is running).

Is this feasible or do I need to consider a different approach to access a user's facebook ID server-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of polluting FB's cookies by trying to change the domain, I would suggest using a GET or POST request to the Flask app in `statusChangeCallback`

Comment: Excellent idea. Thank you!